# Find objects with a certain complex field in null (Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I have a collection of processes. A process can have a field `completion` which is an object including completion information (including competion datetime, and more).

In order to get the active processes I make a simple query `db.processes.find({completion:null})`. That however is not very efficient, and may take a lot of time, if the collection has a lot of completed processes.

We're using Mongo atlas, and it suggests that we add an index `{completion:1}`. But we're not sure it's a good idea, given completion is not a sortable field, but rather a complex object (when it is not null).

What index could I crate to make life easier for a query that retrieves active processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe create a Partial Index.

Comment: So, what happens if you create the suggested index?